# texlua installed but not working

Tags: latex, lua

I've installed Tex Live 2015 following [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/35903) instructions.
When I try to use the script "getnonfreefonts" from the [tug website](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) I get these errors:

```
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
sudo: texlua: command not found

sudo -s
texlua install-getnonfreefonts
The program 'texlua' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install luatex
```

even though LuaTeX is installed.
`texlua -v` in fact shows `This is LuaTeX, Version...`. (If I run `texlua -v` after `sudo -s` though, it says `The program 'texlua' is currently not installed...` again.

Comment: Solved. Use `sudo su` instead of `sudo -s` to become root before running `texlua install-getnonfreefonts`.